# Correct way to invoke the copy module with module param 'content'

Tags: plugins, ansible

I have a custom action plugin and I need to write out returned variable data on the controller to a file. I'm trying this locally right now.

```
copy_module_args = dict()
copy_module_args["content"] = 'test'
copy_module_args["dest"] = dest
copy_module_args["owner"] = owner
copy_module_args["group"] = group
copy_module_args["mode"] = mode

try:
    result = merge_hash(result, self._execute_module(
            module_name="copy",
            module_args=copy_module_args,
            task_vars=task_vars))
except (AnsibleError, TypeError) as err:
    err_msg = "Failed to do stuff"
    raise AnsibleActionFail(to_text(err_msg), to_text(err))
```

The result of ._execute_module is

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Source None not found"}
```

The vaule of result is

```
{'msg': 'Source None not found', 'failed': True, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'content': 'VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER', 'dest': '/home/me/testfile', 'owner': 'me', 'group': 'me', 'mode': None, 'backup': False, 'force': True, 'follow': False, 'src': None, '_original_basename': None, 'validate': None, 'directory_mode': None, 'remote_src': None, 'local_follow': None, 'checksum': None, 'seuser': None, 'serole': None, 'selevel': None, 'setype': None, 'attributes': None, 'regexp': None, 'delimiter': None, 'unsafe_writes': None}}, '_ansible_parsed': True}
```

This invocation is trying to use the "src" param even though I'm only passing the "content" param. I know this because when I add "src" the failure message changes. I excepted, from the docs and from reading the copy module and template module source that at a bare minimum my implementation would result in:

```
- name: Copy using inline content
  copy:
    content: 'test'
    dest: /home/me/testfile
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing or why "src" is being preferred over "content" even though it's not being specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to see that "content" was being handled in the [action plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/a31a8c2a534365f04c15a1f9ba930a6d7ec6fbac/lib/ansible/plugins/action/template.py#L175), not the module. I've adapted what I found to fit my needs. I call the action plugin, instead of the module directly.

```
    copy_module_args = dict()
    copy_module_args["content"] = 'test'
    copy_module_args["dest"] = dest
    copy_module_args["owner"] = owner
    copy_module_args["group"] = group
    copy_module_args["mode"] = mode
    copy_module_args["follow"] = True
    copy_module_args["force"] = False

    copy_action = self._task.copy()
    copy_action.args.update(copy_module_args)
    # Removing args passed in via the playbook that aren't meant for
    # the copy module
    for remove in ("arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"):
        copy_action.args.pop(remove, None)

    try:
        copy_action = self._shared_loader_obj.action_loader.get('copy',
                                task=copy_action,
                                connection=self._connection,
                                play_context=self._play_context,
                                loader=self._loader,
                                templar=self._templar,
                                shared_loader_obj=self._shared_loader_obj)
        result = merge_hash(result, copy_action.run(task_vars=task_vars))
```

This allows me to leverage copy how I originally intended, by utilising its idempotency and checksumming without having to write my own.

```
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "checksum": "00830d74b4975d59049f6e0e7ce551477a3d9425", "dest": "/home/me/testfile", "gid": 1617705057, "group": "me", "md5sum": "6f007f4188a0d35835f4bb84a2548b66", "mode": "0644", "owner": "me", "size": 9, "src": "/home/me/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560715301.737494-249856394953357/source", "state": "file", "uid": 1300225668}
```

And running it again,

```
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "dest": "/home/me/testfile", "src": "/home/me/testfile/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-9531902t7jt3/tmp_nq34zm5"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `content:` argument is just syntatic sugar for [writing it to a tempfile](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.1/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py#L436-L449), so I would guess you will need to take charge of that, or find a way to invoke the [`copy` *action*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.1/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py), which apparently runs before the [`copy` *module*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.1/lib/ansible/modules/files/copy.py).

Comment: I saw the snippet you linked to. I assumed, maybe wrongly, that the point of invoking modules in this way is that the modules are supposed to handle those details for me. I'd need to invoke the module, not the action plugin since after testing I'd like copy to write out to the managed server. Testing with f.write()  locally was step one, moving to copy against localhost step two.

Comment: So by the looks of it, content isn't handled in the [copy module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/a31a8c2a534365f04c15a1f9ba930a6d7ec6fbac/lib/ansible/modules/files/copy.py#L532) but like you said in it's respective action plugin. The assumption I was making is that the invocation of the module would call the action plugin the same was the ansible-playbook would.

Comment: It likely will if you use [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner#readme), which is expressly designed for doing what you're doing (although unknown if it's "reentrant" in that you can call it from within an ansible module). Don't forget that the `copy` action is a _plugin_ and thus python, by itself, cannot know if you have overridden the `copy` plugin -- that's the whole point of having a plugin system, to decouple one thing from another